# Spring Batch Serialization Problems with Java 8 time package

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, xstream, java-time

I have a Spring-batch application that stores several Java 8 time objects in the JobExecutionContext.  I am using the default serializer for my JobRespository.  I am facing exceptions when parsing back out the data that is being written into the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT table.  I have a LocalDateTime that is being stored as:

```
{
    "@resolves-to": "java.time.Ser",
    "byte": [5,
    8,
    18,
    8,
    45,
    50],
    "int": [2015,
    10000000]
}
```

This leads to an exception when I try to read from the previous JobExecution data:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Byte cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.CustomObjectInputStream.readInt(CustomObjectInputStream.java:144) ~[xstream-1.4.8.jar:1.4.8]
at java.time.LocalDate.readExternal(LocalDate.java:2070) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.time.LocalDateTime.readExternal(LocalDateTime.java:2002) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.time.Ser.readInternal(Ser.java:259) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.time.Ser.readExternal(Ser.java:246) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ExternalizableConverter.unmarshal(ExternalizableConverter.java:167) ~[xstream-1.4.8.jar:1.4.8]
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72) ~[xstream-1.4.8.jar:na]
... 97 common frames omitted
```

I am using Spring-batch 3.0.5.RELEASE.  I've also tried upgrading to the latest versions of xstream (1.4.8) and Jettison (1.3.7), but I get the same exception.

This appears to be a known issue with XStream ([link](https://github.com/x-stream/xstream/issues/24)).  The suggestion was to register a custom converter within XStream.  However, spring-batch does not expose the actual XStream object in order to register a converter.  Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: have you add @EnableBatchProcessing annotation on a configuration class ?

Answer (score 3):

Spring Batch allows you to configure your own serializer for the `ExecutionContext` by implementing the `ExecutionContextSerializer` interface and injecting it into the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean`.

You are correct in that we don't allow you to inject your own XStream instance currently (although it seems like a reasonable extension point given this issue).  For now, you'd have to either extend or copy `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer` and use your own XStream instance.

Comment: I have added my own customer serializer.  However, the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` is still using the default `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer`, which is leading to exceptions like this when I try to read job data from the `JobExplorer`:

Comment: `Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot deserialize object with new readObject()/writeObject() methods`
`---- Debugging information ----`
`class               : java.time.LocalDate`
`required-type       : java.time.LocalDate`
`converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter`

Comment: It also appears that hitting the restart button on the Spring Batch Admin UI triggers `JobExecutionController.restart`, which is trying to serialize with the default `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer`.  I get the same exceptions in that scenario (and my stack trace includes XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer rather than my custom serializer).

Comment: Can you please post the configuration for your JobRepositoryFactoryBean in your question?

Comment: <bean id="jobRepository"
  class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"
  p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager"
  p:tablePrefix="SPG.BATCH_">

  <property name="serializer">
   <bean class="org.my.util.BetterXStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer"/>
  </property>  
 </bean>

Comment: Correction:  I actually have a parent jobRepository shared with other jobs in my application.  I have overridden my particular one with the serializer described above.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the configuration?  Also, the rest of the configuration would be helpful (are you using boot, etc)?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem while deserializing `LocalDate` from step execution context.

So I have to make my proper converter :

```
public class DateConverter implements Converter {

    private static final String            DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DEFAULT_DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DEFAULT_DATE_PATTERN);

    public DateConverter() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean canConvert(Class clazz) {
        return LocalDate.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    /**
     * Convert LocalDate to String
     */
    public void marshal(Object value, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        LocalDate  date = (LocalDate) value;
        String result = date.format(DEFAULT_DATE_FORMATTER);
        writer.setValue(result);
    }

    /**
     * convert Xml to LocalDate
     */
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        LocalDate result = LocalDate.parse(reader.getValue(), DEFAULT_DATE_FORMATTER);
        return result;
    }
}
```

After that i have to create my proper `XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer` for using my converter

```
/**
 * My XStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer
 * @since 1.0
 */
public class MyXStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer implements ExecutionContextSerializer, InitializingBean {

    private ReflectionProvider reflectionProvider = null;

    private HierarchicalStreamDriver hierarchicalStreamDriver;

    private XStream xstream;

    public void setReflectionProvider(ReflectionProvider reflectionProvider) {
        this.reflectionProvider = reflectionProvider;
    }

    public void setHierarchicalStreamDriver(HierarchicalStreamDriver hierarchicalStreamDriver) {
        this.hierarchicalStreamDriver = hierarchicalStreamDriver;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        init();
    }

    public synchronized void init() throws Exception {
        if (hierarchicalStreamDriver == null) {
            this.hierarchicalStreamDriver = new JettisonMappedXmlDriver();
        }
        if (reflectionProvider == null) {
            xstream =  new XStream(hierarchicalStreamDriver);
        }
        else {
            xstream = new XStream(reflectionProvider, hierarchicalStreamDriver);
        }

        // Convert LocalDate
        xstream.registerConverter(new DateConverter());
    }

    /**
     * Serializes the passed execution context to the supplied OutputStream.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param out
     * @see Serializer#serialize(Object, OutputStream)
     */
    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String, Object> context, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        Assert.notNull(context);
        Assert.notNull(out);

        out.write(xstream.toXML(context).getBytes());
    }

    /**
     * Deserializes the supplied input stream into a new execution context.
     *
     * @param in
     * @return a reconstructed execution context
     * @see Deserializer#deserialize(InputStream)
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> deserialize(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        return (Map<String, Object>) xstream.fromXML(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

The last step is to register MyXStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer in the file execution-context.xml that register the bean jobRepository

```
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="${batch.table.prefix:BATCH.BATCH_}" />
    <property name="serializer"> <bean class="com.batch.config.MyXStreamExecutionContextStringSerializer"/> </property>
</bean>
```